# Have been trying to validate the below xml, but getting ending tag mismatch

Tags: xml, xsd

This is the xsd which i am trying to convert to json, using jsonix library to compare the schema with either of jsons or xmls which are generated post stream processing in Kafka - when i try to validate the below xsd, got the following error:

> Error :30:3   The element type "xs:schema" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</xs:schema>"   However, the ending tag is there at the last which is "</xs:schema>

Have tried typing the schema mentioned below normally, but its not working.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema
attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
elementFormDefault="qualified"
version="1120"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:cmn="http://***.***">
<xs:import namespace="http://***.***" schemaLocation="common.xsd"/>
   </xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

The fault is on line 13, your complex type self closes but it shouldnt. Therefore you end up with a tag mismatch.

```
<xs:complexType name="eventHeaderType"/>
```

should be

```
<xs:complexType name="eventHeaderType">
```

Edit: Actually, you do this with a lot of your complex types. You close the element and then add the content, and another close tag. That means that the second close tag is matched with the parent tag, and creates a mismatch. So everytime this happens it tries to match a  with your <xs:schema> tag and will give you this error.

Comment: Thanks a million, @ophychius. Have modified the schema as suggested. But this time, post updated getting this error, on the last line in the schema : 

333: 3 The element type "xs:element" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</xs:element>".

Comment: @Basheer you have not closed     <xs:element name="serviceItemIdentifier">
 properly near the end of the document. Try a proper XML editor, or maybe just VSC with XML tools installed. When you format as XML you will see that the tags don't line up properly

Comment: let me check. Thanks for replying :)

Comment: @Basheer Just curious, have you been able to fix the problem?